# Did i can see "pressed" state in UI designer?

Tags: android, xml

I make custom drawables from xml and try to make selector with it.

#### Button

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/green_button_with_solid" 
    android:state_pressed="true" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/green_button_without_solid" 
    android:state_pressed="false" />
```

#### state_pressed = false :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
        android:radius="2dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
        android:topRightRadius="2dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp" />
    <size
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="36dp" />
    <solid android:color="#2ecc71" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#2ecc71" />
</shape>
```

#### state_pressed = true

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
        android:radius="2dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
        android:topRightRadius="2dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp" />
    <size
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="36dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#2ecc71" />
</shape>
```

I set style to my button :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/news_button"
    style="@style/green_button"
    ...
/>
```

But now i'm stack. I want to set pressed attribute to "true" but i can't find this value in UI designer. Is that possible to see pressed effect in UI designer?

I know that this is possible with [setPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPressed(boolean)) method. But it means i need to launch application to see effect.

Comment: If you just want to see how it looks on pressed., you could just interchange pressed state drawables i.e `android:drawable="@drawable/green_button_with_solid" 
    android:state_pressed="false" ` and revert it back after finalizing. Not an efficient soultion though :p

Comment: @AbhishekV damn... is that single solution?

Comment: I am not sure. There could be other solutions.